Why does new Worker('./worker.js') fail but new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url)) work?
When I try to new a Web Worker I find new Worker('./worker.js') fails but new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url)) works.
Almost all bundlers need to pass a URL to the Worker constructor instead of a string literal,
const worker = new Worker( new URL( './worker.js', import.meta.url ) ); 
// bundlers need this instead of the next one
const worker = new Worker( './worker.js' ); 

Vite: https://v3.vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#web-workers
Webpack https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/
snowpack https://www.snowpack.dev/guides/web-worker/
parcel https://parceljs.org/languages/javascript/#web-workers
But MDN fails to mention this. It always uses a string literal as an example.
I can't figure out the exact reason.

If you read the documentation for the latest version of Vite instead of version 3 (the link you provided), the reason is there:

The worker detection will only work if the new URL() constructor is used directly inside the new Worker() declaration. Additionally, all options parameters must be static values (i.e. string literals).

In other words:  Vite does its magic by detecting this exact syntax and no other.

Hi, check my answer. I didn't realize that was because "the path is relative to the current script instead of the current HTML page".

I opened an issue against MDN web worker document and the document has updated according to that


Would be better to use quote marking rather than a screenshot. Also, this seems to contradict the other answer. According to this, new URL(import.meta.resolve(url)) should also work, but the other answer states that the exact syntax new Worker(new URL(url, import.meta.url)) must be used. Could you test it? Which is it?

The other answer was talking about vite, while updated MDN talks about bundler in general.
